# How to declare something is a class in typescript, the same as using the "class" keyword?

Tags: typescript, types

Classes are a bit weird in typescript, in that they seem to be both actual "things" (functions in this case) and typescript types at same time.

Example:

```js
class Test {
  public x: string = 'test';
}

function printX(test: Test) {
  console.log(test.x);
}

function createTest() {
  return new Test();
}
```

Notice how I can say `printX` takes an argument of *type* `Test`, but also use `Test` as a *value* in `createTest()` method. So the same symbol "`Test`" is acting as both a value and a type.

How can I recreate the same kind of construct without using the obvious `class` keyword?

For example:

```js
function makeTestClass() {
  return class Test {
    public x: string = 'test';
  };
}

const Test = makeTestClass();

function printX(test: Test) {
  console.log(test.x);
}

function createTest() {
  return new Test();
}
```

This code will not compile because typescript will think `Test` is a value, not a type.

So is there some way I can tell typescript `Test` is actually the magical dual type/value thing you get using the `class` keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the closest one fulfilling your requirements you may get with something like that:

```ts
interface Test {
  x: string
}

const Test = function Test(this: Test){
  this.x = 'string' as string
  return this
} as unknown as { new (): Test }

function printX(test: Test) {
  console.log(test.x);
}

function createTest() {
  return new Test();
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2p3N)

Here we're defining interface `Test` (type level) for values of our class' instances. And the constructor function `Test` (value level) for creating our instances. Since functions do not have constructor signature baked in we have to assert (`as unknown as { new (): Test }`) typescript that this function still can be used as a constructor with `new` keyword.

This function still lacks a lot of functionality of a real `class`. It does not support inheritance and cannot setup private (in typescript sense) members or methods. Also keep in mind that interfaces also cannot fully mimick `class` instances. As they cannot describe `private` members or methods too.

Comment: Interesting! The biggest surprise for me is that you can have an `interface` and `const` with same name, and they will not clash. TIL.